# Ac voltage measurement

Tags: voltage, ac, adc, measurement, differential

[image]

Hi!

I got a simple problem. My objective is to measure voltage and power factor of a 16V AC through a differential ADC (ADS1115) that measures voltage difference between 2 channels. I only managed to measure current accurately through a CT.

In the positive cycle of the the circuit shown, the voltage across the 1k resistor is 1.45Vp which is measurable. In the negative cycle, the voltage across the resistor will be -14.54V which will burn the ADC.

Hence, how do I modify this circuit to achieve a safe voltage measurement? I will need to detect the waveform at point 0V in order to compare it to the current then measure power factor. I thought of connecting A2 to the ground of the DC supply instead of the nuetral, but I was not sure if that's the right approach.

Sorry i'm a beginner. Any input/ advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to digitize the AC waveform or are you just interested in measuring the peak-to-peak voltage?

Comment: Is your ADC ground the same as the "DC Ground" in your schematic?

Comment: @kjgregory, Just interested in measuring the peak to peak voltage as well as the 0 crossing really for power factor.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Yes indeed it is. The bridge rectifier is also supplying the ADC.

Answer (score 2):

You can capacitively couple and re-bias the AC voltages into the range of your ADC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqwMZg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

VCC is the power supply voltage of your ADC. I've chosen the resistors assuming this is 3.3 V, and that the AC signals are 16 V peak-peak (based on your saying the A1 and A2 nodes in your circuit go to -14.5 V). If I've misinterpreted, you can adjust the resistor values to change the scaling from the AC input to the ADC input.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AD4950, AD8138 or similar differential amplifier. These parts will accept a common mode value from your ADC or a vref circuit and will output a differential waveform centered around that voltage reference. The gain can be adjusted in order to keep the maximum Vpp output (you probably need about 1/4 to 1/8 gain or so). You may need to produce a negative DC supply rail in order to bias the AD8138 into its linear region.

Alternatively, use a second transformer to step down the AC voltage to within the ADC's range. You'll want one with three windings so you can set the common mode of the output with a vref circuit.